# <video> tag for MPEG 4 Visual for firefox and Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, firefox, video

I am trying to play different types of MP4 videos on different browser using HTML5 video tag. MPEG-4 Visual is creating problem in chrome and Firefox. Its working fine in Safari.

Its showing black screen with some audio. Why ??

```
<video controls>
<source src="http://files.parsetfss.com/94875448-ac65-4a73-b70e-b15712c0e187/tfss-f1953154-d56c-  
48be-b018-1762c1063d4c-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="mp4v.20.8, mp4a.40.2">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I am using this code. This video is made from an android phone.

Specs for Video:

Base Media

video codec: MPEG-4 Visual

audio: AAC

Answer (score 4):

Chrome and Firefox do not support the MPEG-4 visual codec. You may want to convert it to the MPEG4 codec on a computer by using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), I hope this was helpful for you!